# .NET / ASP.NET related frameworks I should know about

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, frameworks, application-blocks

Had an interview, and got a question about MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework), which I had never heard about.

What are the main **current** such frameworks I should know about?
(General .NET and ASP.NET)

Comment: What _kind_ of frameworks? Logging? ORMs? AOP? Something else? There are _many_ frameworks in the .NET world, what type are you interested in?

Comment: MEF is not a framework in the usual "framework" sense. It is a new feature integrated into .NET 4 allowing to easily build applications with extensibility features. It also has nothing to do with the Entity Framework.

Comment: I think this Q&A will cover most of your needs: [Most useful free .NET libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries). Of course *knowing* all of them is impossible, but knowing about the *existence* of some of them is probably good.

Comment: What kind of question did you get? If you know what MEF is or something specific about MEF?

Comment: >what type are you interested in?  THe ones I might get questions about:-)

Answer (score 0):

For a job interview i really dont think you should'n need to know eny specific frameworks. Its just luck if you do know that specific frameworks they are using.